# My python module shows error that it does not have the attribute called for

Tags: python, package

I am trying to install my own python package/module. I wrote some functions in a file namely `utils.py`, put it in the src folder. I also created the `__init__.py` and `setup.py`. I installed it from Pycharm's terminal, and it is installed. The package is installed with a name "OMR".

But when I import the installed package/module and call any function from there, I get an error message that the module has no attribute with that name. For example, when I run the following code:

```
import cv2
import OMR as utils
img = cv2.imread("Img.png")
widthImg=800
heightImg=800

rectContours, imgContours = utils.getRectangles_fromImage(img, widthImg, heightImg)
```

This code shows an error:

> AttributeError: module 'OMR' has no attribute 'getRectangles_fromImage'

although the `utils.py` file in the `src` folder does contain this function.

Here is the code in the `setup.py` file.

```
setup(
    name='OMR',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='This program processes an OMR image of specific format. Then it identifies correct answers and scores the script',
    author='Mr Alam',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    keywords=['OMR'],
    classifiers=["Programming Language :: Python::3",
                 "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
                 "Operating System :: OS Independent"],
    python_requires='>=3.0',
    py_modules=['OMR'],
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    install_requires=['opencv-python','numpy']
)
```

Here is the content of the `__init__.py` file.

```
from .src import utils
```

[image: Here is the folder tree]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I think you'll need to put the `__init__.py` file inside `src` and adapt accordingly. Your `setup.py` says that the module lives in the `src` directory and so the hierarchy should follow this.

Comment: Should `import OMR as utils` be `from OMR import utils`?